# android-avoiding activity recreation when clicking notification not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

I have a single `Activity` in my app (called MainActivity) and when I send notification to user, I want it to get opened if the notification is clicked. **the important point is to avoid activity recreation and if there is already an instance of it alive, bring it to front and deliver the data to it**. to get this behavior I have tried:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class)
.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
.putExtra("data", ...);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and in manifest:

```
<activity
 android:name="...activities.MainActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTop"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen.Light">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 activity>
```

but the `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` method never gets called when I touch the notification, instead `onCreate` is called and the activity is recreated. please note that since I'm testing, I send the notification from the MainActivity itself and while it is open, I drag status bar and click on my notification (which then recreates the MainActivity). what is the problem?

Comment: Can you please post your  `new Intent` implementation snippet ? And where are you defining `PendingIntent` ?

Comment: Your code is working as expected and if you are still facing the issue, please share more details to debug and help you with the solution :)

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan I simply override `OnNewIntent` to see if it gets called:
`protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {super.onNewIntent(intent); setIntent(intent); Log.i(TAG, "hello!");`

Comment: as I have mentioned in question, I'm running this code from MainActivity itself, so PendingIntent is also created there.

Comment: I can able to make that work as expected. If want I can post my answer for your understanding.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan are you also sending notification from the Activity itself?

Comment: Yes. I just implemented the local notification within the `MainActivity` and kept the activity open. Then clicked in the notification and update the UI on `newIntent`.

Comment: so could you please share your code with me? (including your activity tag in manifest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you shared seems to be fine and only concern I see is `setIntent()` inside `onNewIntent()`.

May be you can try removing them and check. And next is `getApplicationContext()` that you are passing in the `PendingIntent`. Try passing it as `MainActivity.this`.

Below is my snippet for reference. I done it in `Kotlin` instead of `Java`. However logic is same.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<activity
   android:name = ".MainActivity"
   android:launchMode = "singleTop">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Logic for generating notification residing in `MainActivity`

```
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
    intent.putExtra("DATA", "SENT FROM PENDING INTENT")
    val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        applicationContext,
        0,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )

    val b = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.app_name))

    b.setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Default notification")
        .setContentText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setContentInfo("Info")

    val nmanager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    nmanager.notify(1, b.build())
```

And this is my `onNewIntent()` part

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    Log.i("onNewIntent", "Called")
    intent?.let {
        binder.msgView.text = it.getStringExtra("DATA")
        Log.i("onNewIntent:", "Received new intent data")
    }
}
```

NOTE : With the help of button action I generate the notification from inside the `MainActivity`.

Comment: I tested my code many times yesterday and it didn't work! but now I tested again and it worked!!! It is also working with `getApplicationContext()` and `setIntent`. thanks for your code anyway.